# ribbon.Invalidate Null Exception in C# VSTO add-in

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-addins

I am creating an application level add-in for Word 2010 using C# VSTO. The add-in has a Custom Task Pane with its visibility controlled by a toggle button on a ribbon. The ribbon has been created with XML (not the Visual Studio Designer).

When I call `ribbon.Invalidate` from outside the add-in's ribbon class I cannot refresh my ribbon because it is null. I get a System.NullReferenceException that issues the message:

> Object reference not set to an instance of the object

I suspect that the ribbon is null because the underlying XML is not loaded when it is called. I have tried many things including

[Invalidating Ribbon from Outside Ribbon](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/8c525cdd-ba86-4b34-b621-44eb7240b07a/invalidating-ribbon-from-outside-ribbon)

which suggests defining a class-level `Office.IRibbonUI` in the `ThisAddIn` class, and setting the value of this in the `Ribbon_Load` callback. I still received the exception with this and all other attempts I made. Here's my code:

In the `myRibbon` class I have:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class myRibbon : Office.IRibbonExtensibility
{
     public Office.IRibbonUI ribbon;

     private bool isTaskPaneVisible;

     public bool IsTaskPaneVisible
     {
         get { return isTaskPaneVisible; }
         set
         {
             isTaskPaneVisible = value;

             // This is where the null exception is thrown
             ribbon.Invalidate();
         }
     }
```

and

```
public void Ribbon_Load(Office.IRibbonUI ribbonUI)
{
    this.ribbon = ribbonUI;
}
```

In the `ThisAddin` class I have:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    internal myRibbon myRibbon;
```

and

```
protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
{
    myRibbon = new myRibbon();
    return myRibbon;
}
```

Any assistance in getting `ribbon.Invalidate` to function correctly when called from outside the ribbon class would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than two and a half years after posting this question, the solution came to me while working on a different VSTO project. The issue was with the XML for the VSTO project.

`ribbon.Invalidate` was null because

```
public void Ribbon_Load(Office.IRibbonUI ribbonUI)
{
    this.ribbon = ribbonUI;
}
```

assigned a null value to `ribbon`. And `ribbonUI` was null because the Ribbon XML file was missing a reference to `Ribbon_Load`.

So the original XML file read

```
 <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" xmlns:nsCustom="Custom Namespace">
```

But it should have had `onLoad="Ribbon_Load"` included

```
 <customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" xmlns:nsCustom="Custom Namespace">
```

I revisited the code I wrote and confirmed that this resolved the issue.

Comment: if I could up vote this 1000K I would. This is exactly what I was missing. Thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 0):

Was the Ribbon_Load callback called before you try to use the IRibbonUi instance?

There is no need to call the *Invalidate* method if the Load callback is not yet called. The fact is that your callbacks will be invoked automatically for the first time right after the Load one.

Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: I too believe that `Ribbon_Load` needs to be called before using `RibbonUI`. I attempted to define a class-level Office.IRibbonUI in the `ThisAddIn` class (`public Office.IRibbonUI ribbon;`), but all attempts to invalidate this from events within `ThisAddin` yielded the exception. Is there another way to call `Ribbon_Load` from `ThisAddin` so that I can invalidate the ribbon from an event outside the ribbon class?

Comment: No, there is no need to call invalidate method before the Load callback. You just need to check an instance of the IRibbonUI interface whether it is null or not. If not, you may call the Invalidate method.

Comment: My issue is that the `IRibbonUI` is null so when I call `ribbon.Invalidate` I get the exception. The ribbon object and its methods/properties are available from `ThisAddin`. I have tried calling `ribbon.invalidate` (in the ribbon classe's `IsTasklPaneVisible` property) from the `VisibleChanged` and `DocumentOpen` event handlers in `ThisAddin`. The set property is called, but always the exception (I also tried placing `public Office.IRibbonUI ribbon;` in `ThisAddin`, but no luck there either.) Appreciate any further ideas you could offer.